# How to calculate time loss for the data transmission from host to device in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, data-transfer, date-arithmetic

I plan to write a cuda kernel to machine learning algorithm but I try to compare the efficiency obtained from the device code and the time loss of data transmission from host to device. Is there any tool to help me or what is the accurate method to have this comparison to conclude whether cuda implementation worth to code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use CUDA profiler. It draws nice graphs representing what your program does in time. This will show you both transfer time and kernel runtime. Generally if your algorithm does lots of computation compared to size of data you will see significant boost.

Comment: But the code is not implemented yet so I try to estimate whether the time I spent will worth to efficiency I will get.

Comment: Data is transfered using DMA to card. If your data are big contiguous tables then it will be as fast as copying them from RAM to GPU. This depends on speed of your PCIExpress, RAM and DMA efficiency.
One more remark. Writing code which copies data isn't time consuming. You'll only need to allocate memory on device - cuda_malloc, and copy data to card and then back from it using cuda_memcpy. No more than 20 mins of coding with testing and running profiler.